# Array initialization is causing build to fail - arrayForceCastU

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, initialization

This line of code is preventing my project from building:

```
var allAttributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []
```

I tried `var allAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()` and it too fails to build.

Here are the error details:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Error:
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"__TFSs15_arrayForceCastU___FGSaQ__GSaQ0__", referenced from: __TFC42com_myname...30ClassWhereCodeIs33layoutAttributesForElementsInRectfS0_FVSC6CGRectGSqGSaPSs9AnyObject___ in ClassWhereCodeIs.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What is the proper way to initialize an array so that I may append objects to fill it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That first line builds fine for me in a view controller class.

Have you tried deleting the Derived Data?

Window Menu > Organizer -> Projects -> choose Project. There's an button on the right to delete the Derived Data.

Comment: Well, that did the trick. I also reset the simulator and quit/reopened Xcode. Very odd.